# Meteor: Publish function returns whole collection instead of one object

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

So I want to subscribe to a publish function which only returns one object of a collection.

```
Meteor.publish("singleobject", function(bar) {
    return MyCollection.find({foo: bar});
});
```

This should give me the SINGLE one object of the collection "MyCollection" where the foo property is equal to "bar", right? (There is only one object where this is true ... so findOne() should also work). What it does instead is returning me ALL objects of my collection, even those where foo is NOT equal to bar.

It works perfectly with another collection where there are more than one object where foo: "bar" is true.
I can't really see what I am doing wrong. Can I not subscribe to a publish function which returns only one object?

Anyone has any ideas on this?! :-)

best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... do NOT put

```
Meteor.subscribe()
```

inside of

```
Meteor.autorun()
```

or

```
Deps.autorun()
```

. Everything inside Meteor.autorun()/Deps.autorun() is ALWAYS executed, even if it's inside a template specific .js file. I was thinking every single one of these js files is only loaded when the according template is loaded, which of course is totally wrong.
This is only for structuring your app properly.

So if you want to subscribe to a publish function depending on the template loaded, put the Meteor.subscribe into the router callback functions and subscribe there.

Works perfect for me now! :)

Answer (score 3):

The code you've used:

```
Meteor.publish("singleobject", function(bar) {
    return MyCollection.find({foo: bar});
});
```

doesn't return just one object, but **every** object that has `foo` equal to `bar`. If you want just one (and no matter which one), you should use `findOne` instead:

```
Meteor.publish("singleobject", function(bar) {
    return MyCollection.findOne({foo: bar});
});
```

If you see also objects that have `foo !== bar`, it means that you fetch them elsewhere. There are two possible explanations:

- You have another publish method for the same collection, or
- You have `autopublish` package still on.

Take care of these two things and you should be fine.

---

For subscription, this is the usual pattern:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('channel');
});
```

---

If you want the subscription to only work from time to time, there are few ways to achieve it.

The simplest one is to add a boolean argument to the subscription, and set it to true only if you want the channel to work. In the publish method you then simply return `null` if the flag is false.

More clean way is to track all your subscription handles and call `stop()` on those you don't want to use at this moment. It's nice, but hard to recommend in this version of Meteor as everything has to be done manually, which adds some not really necessary work.

Comment: +1 @HubertOG currently has 1337 reputation so you should definitely listen to him.

Comment: Thanks @HubertOG! So problem is that I had my subscriptions inside of Meteor.autorun() which is not right as I think of now. So ... tried putting the subscribe function inside of Template.templatename.created = function() {} but for some reason that's still not right.
After switching to another page via a standard a href link (--> another template is loaded) the old subscriptions of the template before are still intact. So where do I put subscriptions if I want them to be template specific?

Comment: Few Meteor versions ago `Meteor.autorun()` was replaced by `Deps.autorun()` - see the updated answer.

Comment: Still same problem. It still does not "unsubscribe" from my subscriptions after changing page.